# Rewrite rule is generating errors on apache server error log

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am currently facing a challenge with my rewrite rules, the apache error log on my site logs some portion of my rewrite rule as an error, reporting file does not exist. Example `[Thu Jan 15 17:27:48 2015] [error] [client *****ip****] File does not exist: /home/nst1/public_html/events, referer: https://www.example.com/events/23924/Understanding-Core-HR-Processes-

The Rewrite Rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^events/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ event-detail.php?detail=$1 [NC,L]`
```

Does anyone have an idea on how i can write a rewrite rule that will not generate this error?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing order of your rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^events/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ event-detail.php?detail=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```